# Does FabricJS's toJSON function support video?

Tags: javascript, json, html, canvas, fabricjs

I've been looking through the documentation, and I can't figure this out. I've tried to do some testing, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Here's one of my tests...

If you go to...

http://fabricjs.com/video-element

...and you open up the console and type...

```
canvas.toJSON();
```

...you get the following object...

```
{
    "objects": [{
        "type": "image",
        "originX": "center",
        "originY": "center",
        "left": 350,
        "top": 300,
        "width": 480,
        "height": 360,
        "fill": "rgb(0,0,0)",
        "stroke": null,
        "strokeWidth": 0,
        "strokeDashArray": null,
        "strokeLineCap": "butt",
        "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
        "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
        "scaleX": 1,
        "scaleY": 1,
        "angle": -15,
        "flipX": false,
        "flipY": false,
        "opacity": 1,
        "shadow": null,
        "visible": true,
        "clipTo": null,
        "backgroundColor": "",
        "fillRule": "nonzero",
        "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
        "transformMatrix": null,
        "skewX": 0,
        "skewY": 0,
        "crossOrigin": "",
        "alignX": "none",
        "alignY": "none",
        "meetOrSlice": "meet",
        "src": "",
        "filters": [],
        "resizeFilters": []
    }, {
        "type": "image",
        "originX": "center",
        "originY": "center",
        "left": 800,
        "top": 350,
        "width": 640,
        "height": 360,
        "fill": "rgb(0,0,0)",
        "stroke": null,
        "strokeWidth": 0,
        "strokeDashArray": null,
        "strokeLineCap": "butt",
        "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
        "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
        "scaleX": 1,
        "scaleY": 1,
        "angle": 15,
        "flipX": false,
        "flipY": false,
        "opacity": 1,
        "shadow": null,
        "visible": true,
        "clipTo": null,
        "backgroundColor": "",
        "fillRule": "nonzero",
        "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
        "transformMatrix": null,
        "skewX": 0,
        "skewY": 0,
        "crossOrigin": "",
        "alignX": "none",
        "alignY": "none",
        "meetOrSlice": "meet",
        "src": "",
        "filters": [],
        "resizeFilters": []
    }],
    "background": ""
}
```

...Each element is output as an image with no string saved in the "src."

Has anyone been able to make this work?

Thanks